# git cannot logon on popup window, cannot use stored password

Tags: git, github, passwords, credentials, credential-manager

Today my brain was somehow fuked up so I upgraded git to version 2.29.1.windows.1.
Now every time I try to 'git pull' or 'git clone' etc., it shows a popup window as below. I have two problems here.

First, **even I input the correct username and password**, it show "Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt."

Second, no matter I set credential.helper to manager or store, **it always pops up the window.** However, the password was stored actually.(~/.git-credential if using store and in Credential Manager if using manager).

[image]

Comment: I'm also experiencing Git prompting me for credentials all the time. Didn't happen before today

Comment: Okay, seems to be related to GitHub Desktop which I used to store my credentials. GitHub Desktop isn't logged in to my GitHub account anymore and refuses to connect. When I use the same credentials on github.com, it work flawlessly. I'll try to update GitHub desktop and hope that the problem will resolve itself

Comment: @citronas I am just using bash command, not github desktop... And my credentials works on github.com too. Maybe they are using same backend to handle the logon action for github desktop and prompt.

Comment: Okay, after upgrading my system seems to be even more broken. Maybe it's a GitHub related issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub deprecated basic authentication, see https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-02-14-deprecating-password-auth/

Comment: if you can share how did you locate the post?

Comment: I googled for the GitHub status page and it was linked there

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; If you are still seeing this popup: [image: GitHub Login requesting username and password], it is because your installed git version is too old!

For the slow-witted like myself, who didn't realize I had an older version of git installed (2.28.1 in my case), make sure that you update git to the latest version. As soon as I updated to 2.34.1 I was finally able to authenticate using a github token.